# MongoDB - duplicate records in fs.files table or its OKAY ?..GridFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

My question is When I save file to MongoDB via GridFS in the fs.files table I have 2 similar records in it ..but the diference is only in _id and length parameter ..So I don´t know if it is OK or it problem somewhere in my code where I trying to save files ? ..
fs.chunks table got the same problem but there I couldn´t see any equal values ..
I could show you my select from fs.files and fs. chunks

[image]

[image]

EDIT :

Okay...so now I delete all the documents included in table ..and make new upload with file just ONCE..and look at the output from mongo

and the text mode output from robonongo looks like :

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57144cdb5235ee50191257be"),
"filename" : "fs.files.jpg",
"contentType" : "image/jpeg",
"length" : 32520,
"chunkSize" : 261120,
"uploadDate" : ISODate("2016-04-18T02:56:27.714Z"),
"aliases" : null,
"metadata" : {
    "slovo" : "auto",
    "slovnyDruh" : "word"
},
 "md5" : "f414e665528d8c6f66381d9fd8ce4abe"
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57144cdb5235ee50191257bf"),
"filename" : "fs.files.jpg",
"contentType" : "image/jpeg",
"length" : 114863,
"chunkSize" : 261120,
"uploadDate" : ISODate("2016-04-18T02:56:27.659Z"),
"aliases" : null,
"metadata" : {
    "slovo" : "auto",
    "slovnyDruh" : "word"
},
"md5" : "f604c165cce422f3bec79333dc0b3805"
}
```

Comment: If the content length is different then it's not the "same" content. If you "intended" to "overwrite" an existing entry with the same "filename" with new data, then it's a problem with your code. But your "question" does not show the code. Also "please" discover the "text mode" output in your robomongo or whatever and rather include that "text" instead of images in future posts. There is a good reason why there is a reputation cap on posting images on this site. And that is because the "text" is far better than a screenshot.

Comment: I delete all from fs.files now ..and upload new file ..just ONCE ..look at the edited post ..So is it OK? or no ..?